# Optimal solution of removing duplicates from an unsorted string

Tags: java

I am working on a interview problem on removing duplicate characters from a string.

The naive solution actually is more difficult to implement, that is using two for-loops to check each index with a current index.

I tried this problems a couple times, with the first attempt only working on sorted strings i.e. `aabbcceedfg` that is `O(n)`.

I then realized I could use a `HashSet`. This solution's time complexuty is `O(n)` as well, but uses two Java library classes such as `StringBuffer` and `HashSet`, making its space complexity not that great.

```
public static String duplicate(String s) {
    HashSet<Character> dup = new HashSet<Character>();
    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        if(!dup.contains(s.charAt(i))){
            dup.add(s.charAt(i));
            string.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

I was wondering - is this solution optimal and valid for a technical interview? If it's not the most optimal, what is the better method?

I did Google a lot for the most optimal solution to this problem, however, most solutions used too many Java-specific libraries that are totally not valid in an interview context.

Comment: What about converting string to ch[] and then passing it to create LinkedHashset. And your hashset would not even maintain the order of characters. If you are allowed to use another array then iterate on string characters and do it as `arr[ch]=true`. Still its **O(N)**

Comment: If you encounter an interview question which does not allow you to use fancy libraries, then you can answer by using first an `O(N*lgN)` merge sort on the String to get the characters in order, followed a single `O(N)` pass through the String to remove duplicates.  The overall solution for an unsorted String is then `O(N*lgN)`

Comment: @SacJn What are the performance benefits to this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Interestingly enough, the two libraries I used here are also used in the solutions in Cracking the Code Review. So I am going to make an assumption they're going to work (I can be totally wrong though).

Comment: No performance benefit. But it will maintain your order of characters in string if that is important. Because it would be counter question if you say HashSet

Comment: use StringBuilder if you don't use multiple threads to more performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't improve on the complexity but you can optimize the code while keeping the same complexity.

1. Use a BitSet instead of a HashSet (or even just a `boolean[]`) - there are only 65536 different characters, which fits in 8Kb. Each bit means "whether you have seen the character before".
2. Set the StringBuffer to a specified size - a very minor improvement
3. Bugfix: your for-loop ended at `i < s.length() - 1` but it should end at `i < s.length()`, else it will ignore the last character of the string.

-

```
public static String duplicate(String s) {
    BitSet bits = new BitSet();
    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer(s.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!bits.get(s.charAt(i))) {
            bits.set(s.charAt(i));
            string.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

Comment: I've seen this `BitSet` class around, but never seen it used. I see. Is it usage the same as `HashSet`?

Comment: No, it's a more flexible version of a `boolean[]` that expands in size as-needed. You can also allocate `boolean bits = new boolean[65536];` and work with that.

Comment: Also it's better to use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, as the later one is synchronized and thus has some additional overhead.

Comment: Uncontested synchronization is extremely fast in modern JVM's, and may actually not have any overhead at all. I almost always use StringBuilder myself because it feels cleaner (I'm never building up strings from multiple threads), but performance-wise there's not really a reason for that. Check out, for example: http://www.journaldev.com/137/stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder-benchmarking

Comment: Stupid question - why do we use  `s.length()` instead of `s.length() - 1`? From my understanding, `s.length()` doesn't use a 0-th index.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage because you are using `i <` which already ensures that your `i` will only go up to `s.length() - 1`. Once you reach `s.length()`, they will be equal, not smaller than. If you say `i < s.length() - 1` then the highest value that `i` will reach within the loop body is `s.length() - 2`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt DUH. Wow I can't believe I asked that.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt you've linked the article that proves opposite. See amendment in the end.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Have you read yourself the link you provided? Especially the "Update" part in the end.

Comment: @Aivean, Basilevs I'm sorry, I was too quick with that link. The optimization that I refer to was introduced in JDK1.7: "The server compiler might eliminate synchronization blocks (lock elision) if it determines that an object is thread local. For example, methods of classes such as StringBuffer and Vector are synchronized because they can be accessed by different threads. However, in most scenarios, they are used in a thread local manner. In cases where the usage is thread local, the compiler might optimize and remove the synchronization blocks."

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html

Comment: I just ran a local test and it also shows that both are equally fast if they don't escape the method. In my test the performance differs up to 5% depending on the test run, but this goes either way - no test is perfect.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt [here is the article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-threading-optimizations-p1) that provides more details on the subject. Apparently, under certain circumstances you can achieve negligible performance difference between `Builder` and `Buffer`, but it's definitely not a good idea to rely on it. You have to be sure that your code is running on HotSpot JVM and all necessary flags are enabled. And still you can't be sure that JIT will make particular optimization.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I've been thinking about this question and your answer, and I think this method is quite nice. Reminds me of the question of whether a string contains all unique chars, and that uses a boolean[], and using "int val = s.charAt(i)" where "val" is the index within the boolean array. Since access is constant time, we simply check if the index is true or false. Making that algorithm O(n) and at the same time without using HashSet or BitSet (a Java data structure). We also rely on the fact that ASCII only has 128 unique chars. We still need to use StringBuilder though

Answer (score 0):

When using sets/maps, don't forget that almost all methods return values. For example, `Set.add` returns whether it was actually added. `Set.remove` returns whether it was actually removed. `Map.put` and `Map.remove` return the previous value. Using this you don't need to query the set twice, just change to `if(dup.add(s.charAt(i))) ...`.

The second improvement from the performance point of view could be to dump the `String` into `char[]` array and process it manually without any `StringBuffer/StringBuilder`:

```
public static String duplicate(String s) {
    HashSet<Character> dup = new HashSet<Character>();
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

    int i=0;
    for(char ch : chars) {
        if(dup.add(ch))
            chars[i++] = ch;
    }
    return new String(chars, 0, i);
}
```

Note that we are writing result in the same array which we are iterating. This works as resulting position never exceeds iterating position.

Of course using `BitSet` as suggested by @ErwinBolwidt would be even more performant in this case:

```
public static String duplicate(String s) {
    BitSet dup = new BitSet();
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

    int i=0;
    for(char ch : chars) {
        if(!dup.get(ch)) {
            dup.set(ch, true);
            chars[i++] = ch;
        }
    }
    return new String(chars, 0, i);
}
```

Finally just for completeness there's Java-8 Stream API solution which is slower, but probably more expressive:

```
public static String duplicateStream(String s) {
    return s.codePoints().distinct()
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
                    StringBuilder::append).toString();
}
```

Note that processing code points is better than processing chars as your method will work fine even for Unicode surrogate pairs.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a really long string your algorithm will spend most of it's time just throwing away characters.

Another approach that could be faster with long strings (like book-long) is to simple go through the alphabet, looking for the first occurrence of each character and store the index at which is found. Once all characters have been found create the new string based on where it was found.

```
package se.wederbrand.stackoverflow.alphabet;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Finder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String target = "some really long string"; // like millions of characters
        HashMap<Integer, Character> found = new HashMap<Integer, Character>(25);

        for (Character c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            int foundAt = target.indexOf(c);
            if (foundAt != -1) {
                found.put(foundAt, c);
            }
        }

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Character> entry : found.entrySet()) {
            result.append(entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Note that on strings where at least one character is missing this will be slow.

Comment: This is ridiculous suggestion. `target.indexOf()` traverses the whole string in worst case. You are suggesting replacing O(N) approach with O(N * K) where K is the number of letters in the input alphabet, which can easily consist of all possible chars (as it is not specified otherwise).

Comment: +1 on the thought but -1 on the implementation. Assuming only limited characters are to be used, it would be quicker to amend the other solution and add a condition on whether the result string has reached the size of the limited character set.

Comment: @beyn23 The implementation is to show the point of the algorithm, not meant to be optimal.

Comment: @Aivean, that is true, but under some circumstances this would be way faster than other alternatives. Like finding the letters a-zA-Z in a text book.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand, in order to find K letters in the string of length N only N steps are required with optimal approach (N + K to be more precise). In your case it will be N * K steps. I can't see how it is faster.

Comment: Its faster if N is big and all characters searched for are found, probably way sooner than N. Like in a text book where it's likely to find all normal _letters_ on the very first page. It won't be faster for all cases but for some, so depending on the task this would be a good algorithm.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand to check whether all elements of the fixed set are already found is cheap O(1) operation. To stop when all elements are discovered is good optimization for the linear solution, but it doesn't require separate inefficient algorithm.